# Getting collection data from flirestore and appending into a list so that i can use ListView.builder to build the content in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Im trying to retrieve data from firestore and putting them into a list so that i can build read and build widgets from the data retrieved. I cant seem do both, i can either get the data, or append a list with a fixed value, but i **CANT** seem to **RETRIEVE DATA + APPEND THE LIST WITH THE RETRIEVED DATA**

. Sorry if im not being clear enough, do let me know what do you need, below is my screenshot from my database structure and code snippets.

Database structure :
[image]

Data retrieval code snippet :

```
onRefreshPage()  {
   Firestore.instance
      .collection("testimonies")
      .getDocuments()
      .then((querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.documents.forEach((result) {
      print(result.data);
    });
  });
}
```

List declaration :
`List<DocumentSnapshot> testimonyCards = [];`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to transform the data into widgets. Have a look at FutureBuilder from Flutter: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html and https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#realtime-changes

In your case you can do something like:

```
FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
  future: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('testimonies').get(),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return Text('Something went wrong');
    }

    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
      return Text("Loading");
    }

    return new ListView(
      children: snapshot.data.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
        return new ListTile(
          title: new Text(document.data()['DisplayName']),
          subtitle: new Text(document.data()['TestimonyData']),
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
  },
);
```

Comment: it shows me an error that says "The default value of an optional parameter must be constant."

Answer (score 0):

If I am correct, you want to query Firebase and append the results to a list. In this case, it is an array. Is this what you are looking for?

[Appending data from Firebase to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51601896/appending-data-from-firebase-to-array)